# Capybara webkit driver found overlaps element, how can I click one of them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webkit, cucumber, capybara

Capybara webkit driver see my css incorrectly.
It sees(displays) my button overlaps another button, while selenium driver got no problem.

Is there anyway I can click on it? may be execute script or something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With Capybara you can trigger click events instead of directly clicking on an element like so:

```
page.find("#some_element").trigger("click")
```

The problem is this doesn't work in Selenium. So what you can do is conditionally perform a standard capybara `click` or a `trigger("click")` based on the current javascript driver, which would look something like:

```
if Capybara.javascript_driver == :selenium
  page.find("#some_element").click
else
  page.find("#some_element").trigger("click")
end
```

Obviously this is less than ideal, but it's the best way I've found to deal with situations like these.

Comment: Right on the spot. The WebKit driver handles dropdown menus very badly, and the only way to circumvent this is through `trigger`.